# Find duplicates across many to many relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, many-to-many

I am trying to find potential duplicates in a many-to-many join in a SQL Server database.
I have a database of students attending classes and have the following tables: Lessons, Attendees, Classrooms and Students.
I am trying to find duplicates where the same group of students may have been entered twice for the same date and classroom.
Students to Lessons is many-to-many broken down by the Attendees table.  The LessonID, StudentID, ClassroomID fields are SQL Server Identity primary keys.  Attendees is simply the join table with a compound key of student and lesson.

Lessons:
LessonID
LessonDate
ClassroomID

Students:
StudentID

Attendees:
LessonID
StudentID

Classrooms:
ClassroomID

It is legitimate that the same group of students may have attended different classes on the same day in the same classroom, but I want to flag them up as potential duplicates, in case the record has erroneously been entered twice.
I can’t figure out how to find matching sets of students for the same classroom on the same date.

So, an example of duplicate data I would expect to find would be:

Lessons:

```
       
+----------+-------------+------------+  
| LessonID | ClassroomID | LessonDate |  
+----------+-------------+------------+  
|   335867 |         347 | 06/01/2020 |  
|   335872 |         347 | 06/01/2020 |  
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Attendees:

```
   
+----------+----------+
| LessonID | PersonID |
+----------+----------+
|   335867 |      432 |
|   335867 |     1398 |
|   335867 |     5107 |
|   335872 |      432 |
|   335872 |     1398 |
|   335872 |     5107 |
+----------+----------+
```

Another way to look at this would be:  for any given Lesson, which other lessons (if any) have the same  students in the same classroom on the same day.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you. This smells like homework (I'm not saying it is, but it has the feel of it), so us doing your work for you won't help you if it is. What research have you done to try and complete the task?

Comment: Hello Larnu.  Because of Covid I am working at home, so I guess you could say this is my homework, but I really would appreciate help with it.  I'll post example data...

Comment: @PhilHawkridge you can use https://dbfiddle.uk/ for create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself using the STRING_AGG function to flatten out the hierarchy. I added the following query to the database:

SELECT Lessons.LessonID, Lessons.ClassroomID, Lessons.LessonDate, string_agg(Attendees.StudentID, '-') AS team
FROM Lessons INNER JOIN
Attendees ON Lessons.LessonID = Attendees.LessonID
GROUP BY Lessons.LessonID, Lessons.ClassroomID, Lessons.LessonDate

This gives lesson data that looks like this:

```
+---+----+------------+--------------+
| 1 | 17 | 2006-01-04 | 3-5-10-23    |
| 2 | 18 | 2006-01-04 | 2-17-252     |
| 3 | 18 | 2006-01-04 | 2-16-18      |
| 4 | 18 | 2006-01-04 | 2-6-11-16-18 |
+---+----+------------+--------------+
```

which I can then simply query against.
I will turn this into a stored procedure passing in for my chosen lesson: LessonDate, ClassroomID and its own "STRING_AGG" team of students, as filters.

The STRING_AGG function is only available from SQL Server 2017.  So for older versions you can use the FOR XML PATH('') syntax, concatenating with a hyphen, with a STUFF to remove the leading hyphen:

SELECT dbo.Lessons.LessonID, dbo.Lessons.ClassroomID, dbo.Lessons.LessonDate,
(
stuff(
(select '-' + cast(StudentId as varchar(10))
FROM Attendees
WHERE Attendees.LessonId = Lessons.Lessonid
FOR XML path('')
),1,1,'')
)
as Team
FROM dbo.Lessons

You could concatenate with a comma instead for standard CSV format if preferred.